# How to load youtube page on WebView Android?

Tags: java, android, youtube

I need create WebView which can load a page from Youtube. I don't want play video, I need loading on WebView. I created this code:

```
WebView youtubeView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webViewYoutube);
WebSettings settings=youtubeView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
youtubeView.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com");
```

But when page is loaded then Android suggest me to choose a other program for loading this page. How can I do my task? I must loading this page without standard browser and other.

Comment: that is weird, the suggestion you are seeing is Android Intent in action, you are not using Intent to launch URL and yet you get that. Can you try to load other URL (non-youtube)?? I am thinking Android Browser doing some magic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a device at least running a 2.2 android version you can read a youtube video directly in your WebView by adding this line:

```
settings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try loading http://m.youtube.com instead of www.youtube.com

Comment: That doesn't matter, as YouTube is smart enough to know when mobile devices access it's site and switch to m.youtube.com